# How to call same service multiple time and store data in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, afnetworking

I have a situation where I will be getting more than 25000 records from web service, it is sending using pagination technique.
 so the problem is I just want to store the data so for that I am thinking to run it in a loop but in future records  may vary (i.e 30000,50000 etc)

from backend I am getting on each page 10000 records,but i dont know how many times i have run the loop so how do I handle this problem?

```
-(void)vendorsListCalling:(NSInteger)pageIndex{
    [[ServicesHandler new] callVendorDetailsServiceWithParams:@{@"pageno":@(pageIndex)} CompletionBLock:^(NSDictionary *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error log  %@",error.localizedDescription);

        }else{
            NSDictionary *dict = response[@"params"][@"data"];
            [vendorDictionay addEntriesFromDictionary:dict];
            pageCount++;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:vendorDictionay forKey:@"vendorsDict"];

        }
    }];

}
```

above block is where i stuck .

Any suggestions would be more appreciated.

Comment: Ask back end team to send any other value(object) with data to identify total records get. The object may be bool or integer. Based on that value, you can stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data into sqlite database. And for recursive calling for service, you can modify the same method as,

```
-(void)vendorsListCalling:(NSInteger)pageIndex {

    if (!loader) {
        //Write code to Show your loader here
    }

    [[ServicesHandler new] callVendorDetailsServiceWithParams:@{@"pageno":@(pageIndex)} CompletionBLock:^(NSDictionary *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error log  %@",error.localizedDescription);

            //If it fails you need to call the service again with the same Index
            [self vendorsListCalling:pageCount];

        } else {
            if (!response[@"params"][@"data"]) {
                //Stop loader since you didn't received any data
            } else {
                NSDictionary *dict = response[@"params"][@"data"];
                [vendorDictionay addEntriesFromDictionary:dict];
                pageCount++;

                // Store Data in database here //

                //Call service with incremented Index
                [self vendorsListCalling:pageCount];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: data is only dictionary can i use userdefaults ?

Comment: Since you have large amount of data. It would be better if you can store it in DB or CoreData.

Comment: @manissharma93 it is working but taking lot of time  and app is freezed here .

Comment: @zack So what you can do is either make your call async or show some progress Hud, saying updating data or something

Comment: calls are fine but storing in db taking lot of time.

Comment: @zack You are storing a huge amount of data. So, it is going to take time.

Comment: i am using `fmdb` for sqlite but when i want to show loader , loader is also getting freezed. for loader `MBProgress hud` using.

Comment: @zack Please check my updated answer. If possible call loaded show method in main thread.